# How to get this transition in android?

Tags: android-layout, android-fragments

[Pic 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yGMtt.png)

[Pic 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sgoKV.png)

As i am dragging my finger on the calendar view(in Pic 1) its showing more of the calendar view as shown in Pic 2. Another example is in the Uber app's booking activity. To see the rate card of a specific car type we drag the car type selection layout up and the rate card is shown. How can i achieve this functionality in ANDROID?